# Get RecyclerView item click count

Tags: android, admob, cursor, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview in my android app and i want to show ads in my app, i know how to show ads but what i want to do is get recyclerview item count so if a user clicks on say e.g two items i want to show admob interstitial ad. I searched a lot but couldn't figure it out
Here is my code

```
    public class DictionaryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <DictionaryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
     private Cursor cursor;

    public DictionaryAdapter() {

    }

    public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int position) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dictionary_item_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v, context);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        holder.word.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (cursor == null) return 0;
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Context context;
        TextView word;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            this.context = context;
            word = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordText);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", cursor.getString(0));
                    intent.putExtra("WORD", cursor.getString(1));
                    intent.putExtra("DEFINITION", cursor.getString(2));
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez2F9.gif)

Here is how i get it my main activity

```
 preferences = getSharedPreferences("click_count",MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (preferences.getInt("count", 0) > 2) {
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                }
            });


            editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
        }
```

Comment: tell me clearly what you want>

Comment: i am loading words from database into recyclerview and when the user clicks on the word he is taken to detail activity. what i want to count how many times words are clicked . if lets say two words are clicked i want to show an ad    https://imgur.com/a/mehOEu0         like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply save your clicks count in `SharedPreference`. First pass `context` to your Adapter.

```
private Context mContext;

 public DictionaryAdapter(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    }
```

Then add the below methods to the adapter:

```
private void addClick(Context mContext) {
    int click = getClicksCount(mContext)+1;
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("click_count", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("count", click);
    editor.apply();
}

private int getClicksCount(Context mContext){
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("click_count",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getInt("count",0);
}
```

And finally, use them. Your itemView clickListener will be like:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addClick(mContext);
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", cursor.getString(0));
                    intent.putExtra("WORD", cursor.getString(1));
                    intent.putExtra("DEFINITION", cursor.getString(2));
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                }
            });
```

You can get click counts by calling `int count = getClicksCount(mContext);` methode.

Comment: you code works perfectly fine but it doesnt show ads until i close my app or go back to another activity. i have updated my code please take a look

Comment: @rob you want to show ad on same page or another activity i.e open when you click on item?

Comment: @rob You can implement an interface inside `addClick(Context mContext)` method and update whatever you want by every click. Is it what you want? let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding an interface that defines the recycler view item click listener

```
  public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked();
    }

//update adapter and view holder code as the following

    public class DictionaryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <DictionaryAdapter.ViewHolder> implements ItemClickListener {
    private Cursor cursor;
    private int clickCount = 0;

    public DictionaryAdapter() {

    }

    public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int position) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dictionary_item_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v, context, this);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        holder.word.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (cursor == null) return 0;
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked() {
        clickCount++;

        //Do whatever you want based on the click count.
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Context context;
        TextView word;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final Context context, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            this.context = context;
            word = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordText);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", cursor.getString(0));
                    intent.putExtra("WORD", cursor.getString(1));
                    intent.putExtra("DEFINITION", cursor.getString(2));
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                    if(itemClickListener != null) {
                        itemClickListener.onItemClicked();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting error at these two lines   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dictionary_item_layout, parent, false, this);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v, context);